# How to fix error message "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:" in C?

Tags: c, terminal

I'm currently getting the error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_makeContext", referenced from:
      _main in myThread-68b6d3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

This error only occurs when I use the function makeContext or swapContext from ucontext.h

Here's what the head of my code looks like:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

#include <unistd.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
//#include <sys/ucontext.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
```

I'm in terminal and I'm using this to compile:

```
gcc -w myThread.c -o myThread
```

My code will compile if I comment out all makeContext and swapContext functions. It works fine for the other function in  like getContext and setContext.

Any idea on how to remove this error?

Comment: You appear to have spelled the function names incorrectly.  They do not use camelCase: `makecontext()` and `swapcontext()`.  Do note that these functions are no longer standard, however, having been removed from the 2008 revision of POSIX.1.

Comment: the posted code is missing anything that will cause a compile problem.  AND since your 'compile' statement is missing the option '-c' it will also try to perform the link step.